# Filename generation from variable in zsh without spawning subshell

Tags: unix, shell, zsh, globbing

In zsh I have a glob pattern in a variable, and I want to define another variable that performs filename generation on that pattern. Is there a way to do this without spawning a subshell?

The following does not work:

```
x=foo*
y=$~x
```

Obviously I can do

```
x=foo*
y=$(echo $~x)
```

and the regular completion behavior kicks in.  But the point of this question is to avoid spawning a subshell, which seems like it should be unnecessary.

This question got no responses over the last few days on stackoverflow.com, so I figured I would try asking here.

Comment: Better try on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) in case you won't get many answers here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `y` an array, the parameter `$x` get's expanded:

```
$ x=foo*
$ y=($~x)
$ print -l $y
foo1
foo2
```

If you want a single string, join the array's values with blanks:

```
$ ys=${(j: :)y}
$ print -l $ys
foo1 foo2
```

Comment: This is definitely the best idea I've heard so far.  I was hoping for an answer to a broader question than my original question, which would be "How can we do this expansion without any extra work at all?"  But this definitely satisfies the original question by not spawning a subshell.  Thanks!